# Where to add new element.style in my style.css file?

Tags: css

I have a slideshow that I want to update the element.style that I just made in chrome developer editor. My issue is that I do not know where in my current style.css file I should place this or title it. I have tried the following.

```
#views_slideshow_cycle_main_front_page_slideshow-block_1 .view-field-title a{
position: absolute;
bottom: 35px;
right: 0px;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
background-color: white;
opacity: 0.5;
width: 235px;
}
```

Here is a link to our website. http://www.victorysoccerohio.com/

Can anyone please give a clue on where or how the title should be?

Thank you,
David

Comment: It looks like you have a `style.css` file, so find that file and put these styles in there

Comment: for which ever div u tried writing the css in chrome developer , write your css for that div using a class or id in your style.css file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `.view-field-title` class on your webpage, which may be why it's not applying the style.. Removing this class and the `a` applies your styles to the element:

```
#views_slideshow_cycle_main_front_page_slideshow-block_1{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 235px;
}
```

Comment: What title or wording next to the # sign should be there to tell the style.css file to make those changes below to only that section?

Comment: Thank you for the tips I was able to this to work a round about way which I post later once I have it done.